# Playing on PokerStars.uk from Germany?

Tags: poker-stars

I have a UK PokerStars account, but I'm currently visiting Germany for few days and I was wondering if it's ok to play on PokerStars.UK

I've tried to register to multiple tournaments (real money) and doesn't seem to be a problem

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the terms and conditions about issues like these, or wait for a confirmation from support before playing next time. There is nothing worse than a lifetime ban and your balance frozen.

Comment: Online poker rooms generally use IP blocking to keep players from playing from localities that do not allow online poker. So if you are not being blocked your usually good. However this does not mean your legal were your at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Solved]

Just got a response from PS support stating that it's allowed to play using PokerStars.uk in Germany

Below is there response:

> Please note as a player on the .UK platform you are able to play on this software whilst travelling outside the UK. You are able to play in any jurisdiction where the .COM or .EU platforms (like in Germany except Schleswig-Holstein) are available.